# Showing a polynomial of degree 7 is not solvable by radicals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-groups, galois-theory, radicals

Show that the polynomial of $x^7-10x^5+15x+5$ is not solvable by radicals.

For a polynomial of degree 5, we simply consider the derivative and determine the number of real and complex roots from there. However, with a degree 7 polynomial, this becomes much more difficult.

Comment: How do you determine radical solvability just by 'determining the number of real and complex roots' for a degree 5 polynomial?  At the very least you're going to need to use something like the rational root theorem to eliminate 'easy' cases...

Answer (score 2):

Here's an outline of one possible approach, and I assume you're working over $\mathbb{Q}$. This polynomial, call it $f$, is $5$-Eisenstein, hence irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Now use Descartes' rule of signs to show there are at most $5$ real roots. You can show there actually exist $5$ real roots by the intermediate value theorem by exhibiting $5$ disjoint intervals over which the polynomial changes sign, indeed $(3,4),(1,2),(-1,0),(-2,-1),(-4,-3)$, should work.

So $f$ is an irreducible degree $7$ polynomial with exactly two nonreal roots. Hence its Galois group is all of $S_7$.

It's known from group theory that $S_7$ is not solvable, so $f$ is not solvable by radicals.